# I cannot retrieve the name part in the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, razor-pages, .net-8.0

I am following a developer but I would like to ask for your help for an issue that I cannot comprehend, when I try to bring the name of the Universities to the University field in my own application, I cannot succeed, but I can successfully return UniversityIds, how can I fix this?

My relevant data sets

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public String? DepartmentName { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    public String? Summary { get; set; }= String.Empty;

    public String? ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public int UniversityId { get; set; } 
   
    public University? University { get; set; } 
}
```

```
public class University
{
    public int UniversityId { get; set; }
    public String? UniversityName { get; set; }=String.Empty;

    public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; } 
}
```

Related call field in the Controller section

```
 private SelectList GetUniversitiesSelectList()
 {
     return new SelectList(_manager.UniversityService.GetAllUniversities(false),
         "UniversityId",
         "UniversityName");
 }
```

```
 public IActionResult Create()
 {
     ViewBag.Universities = GetUniversitiesSelectList();

     return View();
 }
```

Below is the relevant field I called on the view page

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>DepartmentId</th>
        <th>Image Url</th>
        <th>University</th>
        <th>Department Name</th>
        <th>Operations</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (Department dep in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@dep.DepartmentId</td>
            <td>
                <img class="border border-dark rounded " src="@dep?.ImageUrl" alt="@dep?.DepartmentName" width="50"/>
            </td>
            <td>@dep.University.UniversityName</td>
            <td>@dep.DepartmentName</td>
```

the error I get is as follows
`fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13] Connection id "0HMVCRVFSALLL", Request id "0HMVCRVFSALLL:0000000C": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Could not resolve type 'AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Areas_Admin_Views_Department_Index' in assembly 'QuizBank, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.) (Could not resolve type 'AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Areas_Admin_Views_Department_Index' in assembly 'QuizBank, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.) ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type 'AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Areas_Admin_Views_Department_Index' in assembly 'QuizBank, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

I am waiting for your help, please inform me about this

I updated the dataset, I tried to convert it to String type, I changed the code blocks, but there was no solution, I get UniversityeIDs but I cannot get UniversityNames

Comment: Looks like there was a compilation issue with your pages. Try cleaning and rebuilding your app.

Comment: Hello, I am getting the following error in the corrections I made according to your advice "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Entities.Models.Department.University.get returned null."

Comment: @Mehmet: Use debugger to see what line of code throws you the `System.NullReferenceException` error. Is this error is throwing in the controller code or in the view code?

Comment: @Jackdaw Hello, I got rid of the empty error, I get the information I want in the page section, but this time when I try to add a university, the UniversityId section that should return when I try to add a university returns empty, I will try the error you mentioned for that part, thank you.

Comment: Could you please share your `_manager.UniversityService.GetAllUniversities` details along with your University table defination?

Comment: ```
 public IEnumerable<University> GetAllUniversities(bool trackChanges)
 {
     return _manager.University.FindAll(false);
 }
''''
```
public class University
{
    public int UniversityId { get; set; }
    public String? UniversityName { get; set; }=String.Empty;

    public ICollection<Department?> Departments { get; set; } // collection navigation property
}
 }
''''
First of all, I thank you for your interest and I apologize for my late return, I have sent you the information you requested
@MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: I solved my problem thanks to the Include method of .Net, thank you everyone for their help

Comment: Thanks for your response, glad to know that you were able to resolve your issue successfully.